# Tumblr template tags to get the last post data?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm trying to build a theme where all the facebook `og:*` tags point to the last post that is being rendered, with a fallback to some information like the blog's title or some such. Does anyone know what the templating tags for this are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved using the `posts` loop with targeting the first block; try a syntax like:

```
<head>
      <meta property="go:title" content="{Title}" />
      {block:Description}
      <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
      {/block:Description}
{block:Posts} 
      {block:Post1}
            {block:Text} {/block:Text}
            {block:Photo} {/block:Photo}
            {block:Panorama} {/block:Panorama}
            {block:Photoset} {/block:Photoset}
            {block:Quote} {/block:Quote}
            {block:Link} {/block:Link}
            {block:Chat} {/block:Chat}
            {block:Audio} {/block:Audio}
            {block:Video} {/block:Video}
            {block:Answer} {/block:Answer}
      {block:Post1}
{/block:Posts}
</head>
```

## Clarification

`{block:Posts}` loops through the blog posts, however, it renders only the **first post** (which is latest per Tumblr posts order) using `{block:Post1}`. Then, each post has a different `meta` tag requirement.